# Do you need to close streams if you close socket in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, stream

I've heard that calling 'socket.close()' automatically closes it's streams.

Would:

```
public void close() {
     try {
          socket.close();
     }catch(IOException e) { }
}
```

Have the same effect as:

```
public void close() {
     try {
          outputstream.close();
          inputstream.close();
          socket.close();
     }catch(IOException e) { }
}
```

If your goal was to completely close the socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, closing the input or output stream or the socket closes both streams and the socket.

However you shouldn't close the socket, you should close the outermost `OutputStream` or `Writer` you have wrapped around its output stream, so it gets flushed. Only you can do that. The socket can only close its output stream, not what you've wrapped around it.

Comment: Oh okay. So you're saying if I use something like `ObjectOutputStream`, it won't  be affected by `socket.close()`, only the streams in the socket will be closed, right? And will closing the outermost streams close the socket's streams?

Comment: As invariably with questions of that form ("so you're saying"), I'm not saying anything of the sort. `ObjectOutputStream` can't keep working if the stream it is wrapping is closed. Closing any wrapper stream closes the stream it wraps. See `FilterInputStream.`

Answer (score 5):

Closing a socket will also close the socket's `InputStream` and `OutputStream`:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close()

Answer (score 0):

You should do this is you have a buffered output stream.  This will flush any data which has not been sent yet.

Otherwise, closing the socket will close the streams so it is redundant.